# How to define `bool` conversion for custom data type?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm extending Python with a new type, and looking [New Types](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/newtypes.html#object-presentation) section of Python manual I don't see anything for bool conversion. How do I specify how my type is converted to a bool?

For instance in the example below native numpy type to is interpreted as Python bool somehow

```
import numpy as np
if (np.array(False)):
  print 'hi'
else:
  print 'hey'
```

Looking at bytecode, this corresponds to `POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE` but this doesn't seem useful for tracking down the conversion logic.

Comment: But `if np.array([True, False]):` will produce an error, one that is subject of many SO questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the Python documentation, under [Special Method Names](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__bool__), you can see that the `.__bool__()` method does exactly this.

```
class MyType(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
    def __bool__(self):
        return self.value != 0
```

If you are still using Python 2.x then the method name is `__nonzero__` instead of `__bool__` (see [Python 2.7 Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/datamodel.html#object.__nonzero__)).

Comment: Hm...I get `'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute '__bool__'` for the example above, but it still works inside of an `if` statement

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov In Python 2 this method is called `__nonzero__()`.